# Some people in my company don't know how to pronounce "Butchers"

Tags: pronunciation

Do you pronounce it like "Badgers" or "Batchers"?

Comment: -1 Because you have not said in which country your company is based nor the English dialect  they speak.

Comment: How anyone can upvote a one line question, devoid of any detail, is beyond me.

Comment: I don't pronounce it like "badgers" or "batchers"; I pronounce it like "butchers".

Answer (score 3):

Neither.

Not even a Cockney - [Urban dictionary; Butcher's Hook](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=butchers) & [Wikipedia: Cockney](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockney) - would turn that U into an A sound. It's a U & it sounds as a U.

British & US pronunciations, phonetic /ˈbʊtʃ.ər/ & sound bites are on - [Cambridge Dictionary: Butcher](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/butcher)

Even accounting for the vowel sound, it's one of those words where the T really is pronounced, at least as a glottal stop. It doesn't get softened to a D or G sound at all.
It's definitely butcher or perhaps bu'cher not budger.
In my own accent - Northern UK - the end R is dropped, giving /ˈbʊtʃ.ə/

Comment: In the north of England you will also hear /ˈbu:tʃ.ər/ as in "boot" https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/boot but I think the question is about the sound of the -t-

Comment: Maybe in the North West - same places as they pronounce 'look' as 'loook' rather than the same as 'luck'. Yorkshire side of the Pennines, far less likely. [Native Yorkshireman ;)

Comment: Thanks for clarification: I confess my ears are southern.

Comment: Welcome. I've added further info regarding the potential softening of the T, which I hadn't considered before. Thanks.